# Java app killed - exit code 139 - no crash dump saved

Tags: java, crash-dumps, native-code

I have a Java application that relies on JMagick (a JNI based wrapper around ImageMagick). I'm dealing with an image that the command-line ImageMagick tools are able to process, but JMagick isn't.

The following code

```
byte[] imageData = IOUtils.toByteArray(new FileInputStream(filePath));
new MagickImage(new ImageInfo(), imageData);
```

causes a `Segmentation fault` and the JVM is killed and exits with error code 139.

I suspect there might be a bug in JMagick code but don't know how to debug it. I am using the following JVM directive

```
-XX:ErrorFile=/home/dusanrychnovsky/crashdump.log
```

but the dump is not generated. The directory is enabled for writing.

I'm running

```
Debian GNU/Linux 7 (Wheezy)
```

Comment: Could it be that there is no file at given filePath and imageData is null?

Comment: How big is the file?

Comment: No, the file is fine. It is a 2.9 MB large PNG encoded image file. Also, ImageMagick's convert is able to deal with the image correctly (albeit it takes 2.5 minutes).